# Find all the PDFs in a folder using Visual Basic in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I am *very* new with using Visual Basic and I am having trouble. I want to open a folder and read all the PDFs in the folder for content. I found this code on the [Microsoft Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-find-files-with-a-specific-pattern?view=netframework-4.7), but received errors regarding expectations of certain codes:

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
    My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.pdf")

    Listbox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
Next
```

[image: Error when testing code in my environment]

Does anyone know why I am getting such errors?

Comment: Remove `As String`, and add the line continuation character `_` to the end of your broken lines.

Comment: You cant use 'As String' in your loop instantiation like that

Comment: @HaoZhang when I added _ it says it is an invalid character

Comment: The sample from the link is VB, you are coding in VBA. There are similarities and sometimes code is adaptable as is but sometimes must modify. Put a space in front of the _ to indicate line continuation.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is useful

```
 Sub Dougsloop()

     Dim Filename As String
     Dim path As String

     path = "path to folder" & "\"
     Filename = Dir(path & "*.pdf")

     Do While Len(Filename) > 0
        debug.print; FileName
        'Listbox1.Items.AddItem (Filename) replace debug w/this
         Filename = Dir
     Loop

 End Sub
```

Comment: Replace debug.print with the commented line? is the debug line printing out the file name and the commented line adding the pdf to a list for storing?

Comment: @AdamH Yes, and its adding it to a list box (which is what i thought you were trying to do). I did test it and it works perfectly :)